# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null при динамической генерации контента

Tags: javascript, json, html5

> Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

При динамической генерации контента. Через JSON генерирую html, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. В цикле создаю ряд объектов, в которые потом после их создания хочу положить новые, которые так же генерируются. 
Как решить проблему?

Вот код: `http://jsfiddle.net/1nadzv87/12/`

Слышал про `$().on('event', , )`, но не знаю как применить, так, что контент генерировался при загрузке страницы, а не при выполнении какого-то действия.

Знаю, 2 одинаковых запроса, это так для примера, в конечном итоге url'ы разные.

```js
$.getJSON( "http://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts", function(data){
        var i = -1;
        var s = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"id":/g).length - 1;
        var box = document.getElementById('box');
        var num = new Array();
        var m = 0;
    while (i < s){
            i++;
            num = m;
            m++;
            var obj = document.createElement("div");
            obj.id = data[i].id;
            box.appendChild(obj);
            
            $.getJSON( "http://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts", function(data){
              var i = -1;
              var s = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"id":/g).length - 1;
              var box = document.getElementById(num[i]);
              while (i < s){
                i++;
                var obj = document.createElement("div");
                obj.id = data[i].id;
                obj.innerText = data[i].title;
                box.appendChild(obj);
              }
        
       });
        }
        
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  
</div>
```

Comment: почему `num` инициализируется массивом, а хранит число `m`?

Comment: `num = m;`, `var i = -1;num[i]` - это что значит?

Comment: В итоге идет попытка взять числовое свойство у числа, получение `undefined` и поиск элемента с `id` = `undefined`

Comment: я ложу в массив все id из json, а потом подставляю num, что бы засунуть объекты из второго цикла в нужный блок

Comment: @aSpectro нет, не ложите - `num.push(m);`

Comment: @Igor хм, и вправду, но все же, что делать с моей ошибкой?

Comment: @Grundy как мне сделать, чтобы функция выполнялась не после выполнения цикла, а во время цикла?

Comment: @aSpectro, не использовать асинхронный запрос. Либо пользоваться `async`/`await`  - пример можно посмотреть в вопросе [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554337/186999)

Comment: @Grundy но это ES6 и без babel будет работать только в последних версиях браузеров

Comment: @aSpectro, да, это скорее ES8 :) но в последних уже работает во всех. в качестве альтернативы можно использовать очередь из Promise

Answer (score 1):

```js
$.getJSON("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts", function(data) {
  console.log("outer data:", JSON.stringify(data));
  var i = -1;
  var s = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"id":/g).length - 1;
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var num = new Array();
  var m = 1;
  while (i < s) {
    i++;
    num.push(m);
    m++;
    var obj = document.createElement("div");
    obj.id = data[i].id;
    box.appendChild(obj);

    $.getJSON("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts", function(data) {
      var i = 0;
      var s = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"id":/g).length - 1;
      console.log(num[i]);
      var box = document.getElementById(num[i]);
      while (i < s) {
        i++;
        var obj = document.createElement("div");
        obj.id = data[i].id;
        obj.innerText = data[i].title;
        box.appendChild(obj);
      }

    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">

</div>
```

Comment: а что было не так, сейчас данные записывает, но все в первый блок, и начиная с id=2, т. е. пропускает первый объект и записывает оставшиеся 2?

Comment: "а что было не так" - Вы не видите разницы между Вашим кодом и моим?

Comment: разница мне ясна, но я не могу ее осмыслить, почему во втором цикле при создании объектов не создается объект с id = 1, а только с id = 2 и 3? data[i] начинает отсчет с 1, а не с 0, если я приравниваю i к -1, то js опять ругается

Comment: @aSpectro что делает вот эта строчка? `var s = JSON.stringify(data).match(/"id":/g).length - 1;`

Comment: я получаю число элементов id из json, чтобы воспроизвести цикл нужное число раз и не создать больше объектов, чем их есть

Comment: @aSpectro зачем второй `$.getJSON` вызывается в цикле, если запросы (и ответы) в нем абсолютно одинаковые?

Comment: это для примера, для второго запроса у меня другой url

Comment: @aSpectro Вчитайтесь в мой предыдущий комментарий. Подумайте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81005/discussion-between-aspectro-and-igor).